# CMS without front-end part

Tags: php, html

I am primarily a front-end developer, that means I like to design the websites myself, including scripts, CSS and HTML.
But popular CMSs won't let me to do that. They generate completed webpages as they need to. But I am not able to override the outcome and I have to use the very limiting default pages.

Once I discovered a small CMS called MNews, which was really useful. It let me to write all the pages myself, and at some point, where I wanted to include an article, I wrote a small PHP script:

```
<div id="article">
<?php
$article_id = 12;
include mnews/inport_article.php;
?>
</div>
```

And it included then the article with formatting I've set earlier in the setting in the CMS.
However, the customers started to complain that the used CMS is difficult and that they are used to WordPress. But I can't use WordPress because of the non-ability to design the pages myself.

So, do you know another similar CMS, which would let me to do the design and including myself?

Comment: Why can't you design the "pages" with a standard CMS? You can use your own templates.

Comment: The question is very broad, if you're willing to learn a new powerful language (`Python`), have a look at [`Django`](https://www.djangoproject.com/) - it fulfills **all** your requirements.

Comment: I had a chance to look at the WordPress and I did not like. It generates robust pages and the time to load is huge.

Comment: Django looks interesting, unfortunately, I am only able to run PHP servers.

Comment: [`Slim`](http://www.slimframework.com/) might be worth trying - though not really a CMS.

Comment: Why are people recommending frameworks like Slim and Django when he's asking for a CMS? Apples and Oranges, folks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Wordpress to create my own pages in PHP. There are two very easy ways to do that.

1. You can create a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) which allows you to run your own PHP command on a page.
2. If you want to have complete control over the page, you can create your own [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/). This allows you to build an entire page from scratch, whilst still having access to Wordpress' features.

Comment: You can increase the page load immensely by installing a cache plugin. I use WP fastest cache, which works really great